# Are there 18.04 LTS new limits on number of Xsessions and XRDP?

Tags: login, 18.04, remote-desktop, xrdp

With Ubuntu 16 I can run both local and remote (via xrdp) desktop Xsessions simultaneously with the same account.  With Ubuntu 18 I can log in remotely with xrdp or log in locally via the physical keyboard and mouse, but not both.  A local login precludes a remote login, and vice versa.  I've confirmed with a test just now that this is new behavior with Ubuntu 18.

The more I test and tinker with this the more I'm concluding that this is not really a specific issue with xrdp but rather a limit on the number of Xsessions a user can have running simultaneously.  Does this sound familiar to anyone?  Is there a config parameter in X or the desktop manager that limits the number of simultaneous logins from an account?  I've confirmed that this behavior exists in both Ubuntu 18 and Xubuntu 18, so I don't think it is the desktop manager doing this - must be X?  This does not affect SSH logins - I can have as many of those running as I like.  Again it takes me back to X and the number of sessions allowed.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the fix for Xubuntu (xfce):

Change your .xsession file to:

```
env -u SESSION_MANAGER -u DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS xfce4-session
```

Comment: I spent way too much time looking for a solution to this problem. Thanks a lot.