# XRDP on Ubuntu 18.04LTS with multiple simultanious sessions

Tags: 18.04, remote-desktop, xrdp, rdp

I have seen [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031519/xrdp-on-ubuntu-18-04lts), and noted this line in the top answer:

> If you are not logout in local, the remote login would fail.

I would like to access my machine remotely *without* logging out on local. I know this is possible, as I've been doing it for a while on xubuntu 16.04 LTS (I believe I had a modified version of [this script](https://github.com/scarygliders/X11RDP-o-Matic) at the time).

Unfortunately I can't seem to figure out why I am unable to do so in the current version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there 18.04 LTS new limits on number of Xsessions and XRDP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042337/are-there-18-04-lts-new-limits-on-number-of-xsessions-and-xrdp)